# PlaySound() mmslib does not play existing sound

Tags: c++, windows

EDIT: Solved. Simply the .wav file was not accepted by Windows. I plucked one of Windows own files and renamed it to what my previous file was called and it plays without problem.

I don't know why this can't play the existing file. Windows gives a chime in that something is wrong but I have no clue what.

I added a check right before to make sure it exists. I have also tried absolute paths.

```
string wavPath = "c:\\frog.wav";

struct stat stFileInfo;
bool blnReturn = (stat(wavPath.c_str(), &stFileInfo) == 0); //this returns true

FILE* fp = fopen(wavPath.c_str(), "r");
if (fp) {
   fclose(fp); //this triggers
}

PlaySound(wavPath.c_str(), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC); //m_hinstance
//C:\\Users\\Wollan\\My Code\\A\\Debug\\frog.wav
//TEXT("frog.wav")
//TEXT(wavPath.c_str())
//(LPCSTR)"frog.wav¨
```

The file plays fine in WMP.

Comment: Check the return value of `PlaySound`. Check the environment's error state. Run the code through your debugger. Perform some debugging.

Comment: Don't use relative paths.  Use absolute paths, ensure that you are passing the same path to stat() and PlaySound().

Comment: Tried relative paths as well with the same value in both of course. "C:\\frog.wav". File exists but it doesn't play off, only a windows error chime.

Comment: @Wollan: `"C:\\Users\\Wollan\\My Code\\A\\Debug\\frog.wav"` or `"C:\\frog.wav"`? Pick one.

Comment: Doesn't work. File exists yes with the check but it is not played.

Comment: Edited your modification of my code. You must add struct in front of stat. #include <sys/stat.h>

Comment: Are you sure it's a valid .wav file? Might want to double check just in case you accidentally called `fopen` in write mode in a previous test. Just because it plays fine in WMP doesn't mean Windows will like it.

Comment: Chet Simpson, you had the right answer. If you add an official response I will be glad to grade you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This following code perfectly works:

```
PlaySound(L"C:\\Windows\\Media\\Cityscape\\Windows Balloon.wav", 0, SND_FILENAME );
```

Adding `SND_ASYNC` fails to play.

Comment: Barik? Still the windows chime casting it to (LPCSTR). Using just L I get: -cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const wchar_t [12]' to 'LPCSTR'- I'm going to look into other wav files now, seems like this should have played by now.

Comment: Unicode or ANSI string is not the problem. Just pass the filename without using `SND_ASYNC` and see if it plays.

Comment: I did it the first time there, didn't work. Anyways, the problem was a bad file all along (see OP).

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd743680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says:

> The pszSound parameter is a file name. If the file cannot be found,
>   the function plays the default sound unless the SND_NODEFAULT flag is
>   set.

And:

> PlaySound searches the following directories for sound files: the
>   current directory; the Windows directory; the Windows system
>   directory; directories listed in the PATH environment variable; and
>   the list of directories mapped in a network. If the function cannot
>   find the specified sound and the SND_NODEFAULT flag is not specified,
>   PlaySound uses the default system event sound instead.

No other case is specified for this outcome.

Therefore, that you hear a chime indicates that the file is not being found, despite your assurances to the contrary.

I'd double-check the result of that `stat` call; I can't even find `stat` in the documentation; it doesn't appear to be part of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

PlaySound(L"C:\Windows\Media\Cityscape\Windows Balloon.wav", 0, SND_FILENAME ); 
Adding SND_ASYNC fails to play.
This answer is right!
It is because the ASYNC mode plays the music after the function returns.
Your code may have exited before the music plays.
use int x, cin>>x, after PlaySound function, you will find that it works well.